# Using GS to Import data from GA4 runRealtimeReport into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-api

On Google AppsScript, I have been trying to pull real-time user data from a GA4 property into a google sheet. However, I keep getting the following error message:
"API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication creden..."

Here's my attempt below:

```
async function test4() {
  var theAuthorization = "Bearer " + [[oAuthtoken]];
  var theRequestBody = {"dimensions":[{"name":"country"}],"metrics":[{"name":"activeUsers"}],"limit":"10","orderBys":[{"metric":{"metricName":"activeUsers"},"desc":true}],"returnPropertyQuota":true,"minuteRanges":[{"name":"1minute","startMinutesAgo":2,"endMinutesAgo":0}]};
  var theOptions = {method: 'POST',headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': theAuthorization}, body: theRequestBody};
  const response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/[GA4property]:runRealtimeReport?key=[[API key]]", theOptions);
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(response));
}
```

I have already enabled the necessary APIs and scopes.

1. I think I'm doing something wrong with the Authorization variable. How do I generate the latter?
2. Is the API key even necessary in this case?

I have tested the request body on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runRealtimeReport and it works.

Thank you beforehand for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

I'm not sure how you came up with `[[oAuthtoken]]`, but I guess it's not a valid `oAuthToken`.

In order to get that, you should:

- Make sure that the script is authorized with one of the method scopes (e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly`). You could, for example, set that as an [explicit scope](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes).
- Use [ScriptApp.getOAuthToken](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken) to get the token (e.g. `const oAuthtoken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();`).

Also, you're right, the API key is not necessary. Since you provide an OAuth token, the API key is completely superfluous.

#### Use Analytics Data Service:

A much easier way to call this API is to use [Analytics Data Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analyticsdata):

```
AnalyticsData.Properties.runRealtimeReport(theRequestBody, yourProperty);
```

In this case, Apps Script handles authorization for you, so you don't have to worry about OAuth tokens.

Also, since it's an [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), you'll first have to [enable it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could not find documentation for the the realtimereport in the Analytics Data Service API. That was definitely much easier.